# How to combine headers route by kong?

Tags: kong

I am using Kong to route the client requests. Client will set different keys to the reuquest header,

```
{
  name='jack',
  gender='man'
}
```

As you can see above, there are two keys in the request header, i want that if the reuqest header bring 'name=jack' or 'gender=man' should route to the same service, but how to write the route rule in Kong with db-less mode?

how to write the route rule in Kong with db-less mode?

Answer (score 0):

For two different header keys, you have to create two separated routes. That's because header keys are a logical `AND`. Only values are logical `OR`. So your definition would look like:

```
services:
  - name: my-service
    url: https://example.com
    routes:
      - name: name-header-route
        headers:
          name: ["jack"]
        paths: ["/same-path-for-both-routes"]
      - name: gender-header-route
        headers:
          gender: ["man"]
        paths: ["/same-path-for-both-routes"]
```